# RAILS EXCEPTION: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, https

I can't figure out why in the following line of code

```
res = https.get(url, nil)
```

The application stops and give me the following exception:

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

The strange things is that this error happens only in my development enviroment, when I put the application online (heroku), everyhthing work like a charm.
That above line of code, use this inclusion:

```
require 'net/https'
```

Is anybody able to explain me why ?
Tnx

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to pass any headers just use:

```
res = https.get(url, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

in the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) for `Net::HTTP` this method definition is

```
def get(path, initheader = {}, dest = nil, &block) # :yield: +body_segment+
  res = nil
  if HAVE_ZLIB
    unless  initheader.keys.any?{|k| k.downcase == "accept-encoding"}
      initheader["accept-encoding"] = "gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3"
      @compression = true
....
```

in your code `initheader` is `nil` so error happens on line four `initheader.keys` It may work fine on heroku because there is `if HAVE_ZLIB` which can be `faulse` so code is skipped.

Comment: So what do you suggest to pass on the second parameter instead than nil? Please note that I use HTTPS and not HTTP, is the same method call ?

Comment: yes it is the same ` @http = Net::HTTP.new(PANEL, 443) @http.use_ssl = true` pass only one parameter or some info You can find more http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/788 but check comments also

Comment: Tnx, I could try tonight ...The strange thing is that the developers that works with me, does not have this problem on their Unix enviroments. Do I have to include or import some linux libraries or something like that ?